# How does delegate.Invoke work?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, invoke

If I create a delegate in my code like :

```
delegate void dostuff (string o);
```

This generates a class that derives from `System.MulticastDelegate` which implements three methods - `Invoke`, `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke`.

If I look at the compiled IL for `Invoke` all I see is :

```
.method public hidebysig newslot virtual 
        instance void  Invoke(string o) runtime managed
{
} // end of method dostuff::Invoke
```

The method contains no code. Calling it does work - the delegate gets invoked, but I can't see how it does it.

Where does the voodoo that makes calling Invoke actually call the delegate come from?

Comment: It's just part of the underlying .Net framework -- the call *is* the call to invoke. `MyDelegate.Invoke()` is the same as `MyDelegate()`

Comment: MyDelegate() is just syntactic sugar that gets compiled down to MyDelegate.Invoke() - a call to the generated Invoke method. The IL for the call is simply *callvirt   instance void ConsoleApplication1.Program/dostuff::Invoke(string)* which is no different from any other method call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The voodoo can be found at the end of the signature: `runtime managed`. Notice that all of your managed classes and methods that you define will be decorated as `cli managed`.

`runtime managed` means that the runtime provides pre-optimized implementations of the methods.

Comment: The delegate does have behaviour. It loops over its invocation list - a delegate can represent multiple methods to call - and calls each method in turn.

Comment: I can't see how the implementing method can override the behaviour. It is an interesting pattern, but I can't see any evidence of this being the way it works. It wouldn't work for multicast delegates though. When creating the delegate it is definitely the generated delegate class that gets created and its constructor is called with the method passed to it. There is no voodoo here, it is just creating the generated delegate class just like any normal class is created.

Comment: @Mongus, updated my answer. Note however that the "behavior" for iterating over the invocation list is not part of delegate, but part of System.Delegate.

Comment: @Mongus: all delegates have been multicast since at least .NET 2.0.

Comment: ah! So it is voodoo after all! Thanks ;)