# Where exactly is SomeDelegate.Invoke implemented and how is it "wired" to the delegate classes

Tags: c#, delegates, clr

Where exactly (CLR source file) can in find the actual implementation of the `SomeDelegate.Invoke` method?

How does the .Net runtime knows that calling `SomeDelegate.Invoke` should result in calling that implementation? Keep in mind that the `SomeDelegate.Invoke` method can have any number of arguments.

Comment: As for how it's actually done, I'm not sure, but I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388466/how-does-delegate-invoke-work

Comment: Yes, I know about the existence `runtime` call. But I need the lower-level information.

Comment: comdelegate.cpp is the start point, but you'll quickly get lost in the mountain of code that's underneath it.  The "stub compiler" is a very non-trivial piece of code.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. Looks like I found what I wanted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25097048/1497385 I stumbled upon the comdelegate.cpp before, but I only saw the implementations of the `Delegate`/`MulticastDelegate` methods there and couldn't establish the link between the code there and custom delegates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is how the voodoo magic works (from what I found by glancing over the sources for an hour):

1. At some time, the method table for the `SomeDelegate` class is populated and the runtime stumbles upon the `Invoke` method.
2. The `PreStubWorker` (`vm\prestub.cpp`) is called, which calls `DoPrestub`, which calls `MakeStubWorker`
3. The `MakeStubWorker` sees that the method is runtime-implemented (`pMD->IsEEImpl`), asserts that the method table (why ask the method table?) looks like a delegate and calls `COMDelegate::GetInvokeMethodStub` (`vm\comdelegate.cp`p) to create the stub.
4. The `COMDelegate::GetInvokeMethodStub` method (`vm\comdelegate.cpp`) calls `COMDelegate::TheDelegateInvokeStub` which calls the `EmitDelegateInvoke` and `EmitMulticastInvoke` methods.
5. The `StubLinkerCPU::EmitDelegateInvoke` and `StubLinkerCPU::EmitMulticastInvoke` methods are implemented in the `vm\i386\stublinkerx86.cpp` file (for x86) and `vm\ppc\cgenppc.cpp` (for PowerPC). These methods are quite short and emit the concrete assembly/CPU-specific implementations of the `Invoke` methods.
6. The reference to the method implementation is put to the `SomeDelegate`'s method table.